# Form resizing leaves ghosted lines

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My searching terms most not be correct.  I am having an issue when I resize a form a line is left behind showing the size of form it once was.  I am using dual monitors and the issues is only happing on one of the monitors.

I did disable DPI awareness to solve another issue I was having with the forms in the app being scaled down when using a third party control.  Below is what I added to the app.config.  I do not have the issue with the ghosted line if the below code is removed.

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
    <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="false" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the .NET version you're targeting. `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing` was introduced (.NET Fx 4.6.1, IIRC) to correct scaling discrepancies of some Controls (e.g., DataGridView scaling correctly, DataGridViewComboBoxColumn not so much) -- If your app is scaled when a third-party Control (probably WPF) is used, then your app is not exactly DpiAware on its own. Or you haven't taken good care of the `AutoScaleMode` and the `AutoScaleDimensions` that come with it. The scale factor is determined by either the DPI or the Font. Or not scaled if `None` is selected

Comment: DpiAwareness is a design decision, you have to design for that, selecting the scale mode (which needs to apply the same way to all main Containers, e.g., Forms and UserControls), handling DPI change messages, using scalable Containers (TablelayoutPanels / FlowLayoutPanels), nesting containers, anchoring and docking correctly, and so on. It's a whole process, not something you can fix on the fly changing a couple of settings. Also make sure that app.manifest specifies the supported System versions

Comment: The target is Framework 4.8.

I understand the needing to adjust the location and size of the controls.  All the controls and containers are being handled to adjust to to correct location and size.

The issue is with the lines that are left behind when I stretch the form bigger.    If I use the mouse to resize the form wider a line is displayed on the form from where the edge of the form once was.  If I drag the form slowly more lines are produced.  If mouse moves more quickly the lines are spaced farther apart.

Comment: When `AutoScaleMode` is set to either `Dpi` or `Font`, the scale factor is determined comparing those values with the current of each Monitor. Then the `Scale()` method of the Forms, the UserControls, then each child Control is called. I.e., the window is automatically scaled to the current viewport. If you don't see that, your app is not DpiAware (`PerMonitorV2`, maybe `SystemAware`, because of WPF elements you introduced, then all Monitors have the same scale) -- If you see graphic debris when resizing a Form, check what your code is doing -- Also make a test with a clean .NET 7+ application

Comment: Make sure you design your test app at 100% scale, pick the same `AutoScaleMode` for all Containers and design the rest for that scale mode. Keeping in mind that Font scaling is not the same as DPI scaling

Comment: Are you saying I do not have a form or control setup correctly and this is what is causing the lines?

Comment: That's possible. Maybe some graphic *adjustments* in OnPaint are causing that effect (unless you're using CreateGraphics somewhere, that's going to work badly no matter what). Or something about *handling* stuff in *All the controls and containers are being handled to adjust to correct location and size*. That's what I can say, since I know nothing about your application (or how you're *handling* the resizing procedure). What I know is that the glitch you're mentioning is not something you usually see

Comment: It is just strange that the issue only shows on 1 monitor and works as expected on another.  I will hunt through all the controls and see how they may be set differently.

Comment: As mentioned, before going on a hunt for inconsistencies in an existing app (may take quite a while), build a .NET 7/8 application, add a couple of TableLayoutPanels (say, one at the top and one at the bottom of a Form), one of them child of a Panel, the other direct child of the Form. Dock or anchor to all sides the two parts. Add some Controls to the TLPs, configured to auto-size rows and columns. Change the DpiAwareness to PerMonitorV2 (defaults to SystemAware) in the Project's properties. See how it goes in the unruly Monitor